# Does Prototype's Array.compact() filter recursively for multidimensional arrays?

Tags: prototype, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm just wondering if Prototype's helper functions Array.compact() and Array.without() filter for multidimensional arrays. It doesn't look like it, and if so, was there a reason for this or is there another helper function in Prototype that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js) itself:

```
  function compact() {
    return this.select(function(value) {
      return value != null;
    });
  }
```

So I guess the answer is no. But wouldn't it be easy to implement your own helper function to do this? just run compact in a loop on the sub arrays.